# Simulator lag when scrolling UICollectionView on XCode 7.1.+

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

Since updating to XCode 7.1, I am experiencing issues with using UICollectionView with simulator. Simulator always stops working (rainbow wheel appears) after few scrolling events on any UICollectionView.

This problem appears only in simulator, app works perfectly fine on device. This issue was not there with the previous XCode version. Also, updating to 7.1.1 did not help.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is discussed in more detail in Apple's forums at https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24274

The issue is that there's a delay in transferring some accessibility information between the sim runtime and host which some users are hitting.  Try disabling Flexiglass, Better Touch Tool, Accessibility Inspector, or any other utilities which may be requiring that data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, BetterSnapTool was causing it. It still sucks though, because I use this utility a lot and disabling it is not a solution for me.

Comment: Right.  It is a bug in the simulator, so it should be fixed in a future release.  For now, you'll have to work around the issue.  Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I think this problem is due to memory , increase the system RAM because xcode 7.1 is heavy then earlier one .

Comment: I dont think that is an issue, I am using the latest Retina MBP with 16GB of RAM.